# how can i give support to other language in android(4.2.x or lower)?

Tags: android, fonts

I am developing one app in that i am getting data in Gujarati font and also in English fonts but when i try to typeface that fonts it didn't give me right output.
i stored data in local database and in samsung device it shows perfectly. but other than samsung it gives me crappy output for gujarati language. so when i used other custom fonts for gujarati than it also convert english fonts into gujarati.

so i am wondering if there is any way that we find out which font is currently displaying.

like if i get english font than i won't change its fonts and if i get other than english font than i will apply custom fonts for that.

if anyone can help me that would be really great. :)

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Better to use String.xml under res/values-gu/string.xml  this is best one check below screen shot

check below screen. u will get better idea.[image]

Comment: thanks .. but it didn't help me ... in my app i got gujarati words dynamically and also gujarati and english both combined if you know any font file for gujarati than it will help me..